# Why doesn't the spider return any response for this site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrap [this site](http://www.bayt.com/) but when I run the spider I don't see any response.

I tried reddit.com and quora.com and they both returned data (started to crawl) but not the site I want.

Here is my simple spider:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule

class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "jobs"
    allowed_domains = ["bayt.com"]
    start_urls = (
                  'http://www.bayt.com/',
                 )

    rules = [
                Rule(
                    LinkExtractor(allow=['.*']),
                )
    ]
```

I tried several combinations of urls in the start_urls but nothing seemed to work.

Here is the log after running the spider:

```
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: bayt)
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bayt.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['bayt.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'bayt'}
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-12-13 20:31:45 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.bayt.com/en/jordan/> from <GET http://www.bayt.com/>
2015-12-13 20:31:46 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.bayt.com/en/jordan/> (referer: None)
2015-12-13 20:31:46 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-13 20:31:46 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 881,
'downloader/request_count': 2,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
'downloader/response_bytes': 2320,
'downloader/response_count': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 18, 31, 46, 212468),
'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 18, 31, 45, 138408)}
2015-12-13 20:31:46 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: you are missing the `callback` method on your rule, share all your spider code.

Comment: @eLRuLL this is all my spider code, the `parse`  method is called by default if no callback is specified, but this is not the problem.

This exact code will return crawling data if i just change _bayt_ to _reddit_

Comment: share your logs then, I tried that `LinkExtractor` and it is getting links.

Comment: @eLRuLL edited the question. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are not using the rules as you mentioned, you have your own `parse` method, which is not ok, `CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method so you shouldn't override that method.

Now, if you are still getting items when overriding the `parse` method, it is because `parse` is the default method for the `start_urls` requests, so the requests are not really following the rules, but only crawling urls inside `start_urls`

Just change the name of your parsing method from `parse` to a different one, and specify that on your rule as a `callback`.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because I still see results for the start_urls parse method for reddit and quora but not bayt.

it seems like they were blocking my request thinking I'm a bot, I edited the settings.py of the project and set the user_agent to `localhost` and it worked.

Comment: aren't you overriding your own `parse` method on your spider?

Comment: No I wasn't, I was just testing running the spider without any processing in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I did `Curl www.bayt.com` in the command line and it seems that they redirect the request to `http://www.bayt.com/en/jordan/`

I put that as My start_urls and it worked and changed the user agent in the settings.py to localhost and it worked.